# Position of const keyword

Tags: c

What's the difference between the following three pointer declarations in C:

```
void * const myPointer1;
void const *myPointer2;
const void *myPointer3;
```

And which one is used to prevent:

```
myPointer = somethingElse;
```

Comment: Don't tell me that you tried to research about it and you haven't found anything.

Comment: Don't miss `const void * const myPointer;` :)

Comment: @LihO I did but found nothing that was pure C (not C++ or ObjC) and that was for simple pointer types without mixing in functions.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Read the rules from right to left:

```
void * const myPointer1;
```

myPointer1 is a `const` pointer to `void`.

```
void const *myPointer2;
```

myPointer2 is a pointer to a `const` `void`.

```
const void *myPointer3;
```

myPointer3 is a pointer to a `void` `const`.

Conclusions:

- `myPointer1` is what you are looking for -- it's a `const` pointer, so its value cannot be modified
- `myPointer2` and `myPointer3` are the same thing
- `myPointer2` and `myPointer3` are kind of meaningless -- dereferencing a `void*` does not make sense

Comment: Your type 2 and 3 (`const void *`) are very meaningful and required if you want to assign from another `const` pointer, such as `const char * s = "..."; const void * vp = s;`

Answer (score 1):

In some places, you can put the `const` in front of whatever is declared `const`:

```
const int * x;  // pointer to constant int
```

You can *always* put the `const` *after* whatever is declared const:

```
int const * x;       // pointer to constant int
int * const x;       // constant pointer to int
int const * const x; // constant pointer to constant int
```

Hence, my personal recommendation, *always* have the `const` trailing, because that's the only "rule" that can be adhered to consistently.

Answer (score 0):

- `myPointer1` is a `const` pointer to `void`.
- `mypointer2` and `myPointer3` are both pointers to `const void`.

The difference between `myPointer2` and `myPointer3` declarations is just a matter of style.

NB: `const void` means here that the pointed data is `const`. Nothing to do with `void` from `int main(void)` for instance.

Comment: What would be the meaning of `void` type (or `const void` for that matter)? E.g., what can be assigned into the address pointed by such pointer (`*mypointer2 = ?`)

Comment: @icepack: A `void *` is a "generic pointer", i.e. a "pointer to whatever". You would assign another pointer's value to it, like `mypointer = otherpointer`. You wouldn't assign value to the *dereferenced* pointer, though.

Comment: @DevSolar Yes, I'm aware of that. I was wondering about the semantic meaning of "pointer to void". Sounds to me that such a description is logically incorrect. `void` here is an alias for "anything" in contrast to a normal meaning of `void`.

Comment: @icepack: No, it's a "void pointer": The pointer itself exists alright, but it doesn't point to anything (useable). You can cast it to a different pointer type, and use *that* for further processing. (See `malloc()`.) So the use of "void" isn't as misled as it might seem.

Answer (score 0):

1. `void * const myPointer1;` = declare myPointer1 as **const pointer to void**
2. `void const *myPointer2;` = declare myPointer3 as **pointer to void const**
3. `const void *myPointer3;` = declare myPointer3 as **pointer to const void**

Whenever in such kinda doubts, you can use:: [cdecl.org](http://cdecl.org/)

You should try **myPointer1** to avoid the condition you explained as it is a `const pointer`.

Comment: BTW. http://cdecl.org/ doesn't support the "void const *myPointer2;". Which is why I landed on this page, googling to confirm what I remembered, that way 2 is the same as way 3.